# iPhone: UIImagePickerController - standard zoom control doesn't work

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a UIImagePickerController that is presented as a modal view controller. This works fine, except for when I try to add anything to the camera overlay view.

As soon as I modify the camera overlay view, the default zoom control stops working (although tap to focus still works). If I tap on the view, the zoom slider appears, but I am not able to slide it up and down like usual.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
        imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;     
        imagePickerController.allowsEditing = NO;
        imagePickerController.delegate = self;
        imagePickerController.showsCameraControls = YES;
        imagePickerController.wantsFullScreenLayout = NO;
        [imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView addSubview:overlayView];

        [self presentModalViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES];
```

Has anyone had a similar problem or can see what I'm doing wrong? I know it should work, as I've seen it on other apps that also use the default camera controls.

Thanks :)

Comment: My first guess would be that what you added to the view is covering the controls. But on a general architectural level, I think you are supposed to set showCameraControls to NO if you are customizing the view. Also for customized recording I think apple is pushing AVFoundation. You can find an example of that in the AVEditDemo from here http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/

Comment: I have checked and tried lots of different things, and it appears that the view is not covering the controls. Making a small view in the top left corner that definitely doesn't cover the controls still results in the zoom slider being 'locked' and I can't slide it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of mucking round I've finally come across a solution. Don't use the cameraOverlayView property, instead add a subview to the UIImagePickerController with a frame of size CGRectZero.

In the following example, overlayView is a custom subclass of UIView which draws an image and passes touches through to the next responder:

```
OverlayView *overlayView = [[OverlayView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {
        imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;     
        imagePickerController.allowsEditing = NO;
        imagePickerController.delegate = self;
        imagePickerController.showsCameraControls = YES;
        [imagePickerController.view addSubview:overlayView];
        statViewController.imagePickerController = imagePickerController;
    }
```

-

And then, everything just works. Not sure if adding a subview to UIImagePickerController is documented and ok with Apple, but heaps of other apps use this (or a similar workaround) so shouldn't cause any submission problems.

Comment: Can you explain by what you mean by the last line "statViewController.imagePickerController = imagePickerController;" ? Are you adding  imagePickerController to something else, like the view controller?

Comment: Yes - 'statViewController' is a viewController that needs to use the imagePickerController. Later on, the statViewController will call something like "[self presentModalViewController:imagePickerController]". That line isn't really important though - as long as you initialise your imagePicker as above and present it as per norm then it should work (assuming I'm not forgetting anything).